# Case Insensitive Unique Array Elements in Perl

Tags: perl, uniq

I am using the uniq function exported by the module, List::MoreUtils to find the uniq elements in an array. However, I want it to find the uniq elements in a case insensitive way. How can I do that?

I have dumped the output of the Array using Data::Dumper:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
use feature "say";

my @elements=<array is formed here>;

my @words=uniq @elements;

say Dumper \@words;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'John',
          'john',
          'JohN',
          'JOHN',
          'JoHn',
          'john john'
        ];
```

Expected output should be: john, john john

Only 2 elements, rest all should be filtered since they are the same word, only the difference is in case.

How can I remove the duplicate elements ignoring the case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use lowercase, [`lc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html) with a [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) statement:

```
my @uniq_no_case = uniq map lc, @elements;
```

---

The reason [`List::MoreUtils'`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils) `uniq` is case sensitive is that it relies on the deduping characteristics of hashes, which also is case sensitive. The code for `uniq` looks like so:

```
sub uniq {
    my %seen = ();
    grep { not $seen{$_}++ } @_;
}
```

If you want to use this sub directly in your own code, you could incorporate `lc` in there:

```
sub uniq_no_case {
    my %seen = ();
    grep { not $seen{$_}++ } map lc, @_;
}
```

Explanation of how this works:

`@_` contains the args to the subroutine, and they are fed to a `grep` statement. Any elements that return true when passed through the code block are returned by the grep statement. The code block consist of a few finer points:

- `$seen{$_}++` returns 0 the first time an element is seen. The value is still incremented to 1, but after it is returned (as opposed to `++$seen{$_}` who would inc first, then return).
- By negating the result of the incrementation, we get true for the first key, and false for every following such key. Hence, the list is deduped.
- `grep` as the last statement in the sub will return a list, which in turn is returned by the sub.
- `map lc, @_` simply applies the `lc` function to all elements in `@_`.

Comment: And this is the same uniq function exported by List::MoreUtils module?

Comment: Indeed it is. Although since the sub is so simple and short, you can just copy paste it, and save yourself loading the module.

Comment: Thanks. I will understand the subroutine and then use it directly :) Can you explain the grep syntax a little? The hash, %seen is using the elements of the array as a key and checking for their occurrence. But, I am not sure, how this entire syntax works.

Comment: @NeonFlash Added an explanation in my answer. It is a fairly cleverly written sub, I think.

Comment: @NeonFlash If this answer solves your problem to your satisfaction, don't forget to accept it by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: This version of the syntax is slightly more malleable: my @uniq_no_case = uniq map {lc $_} @elements;

Comment: Having this line instead will preserve the case of the array: `grep { not $seen{lc $_}++ } @_;`

Answer (score 6):

Use a hash to keep track of the words you have already seen, but also normalize them for upper/lower case:

```
my %seen;
my @unique;
for my $w (@words) {
  next if $seen{lc($w)}++;
  push(@unique, $w);
}
# @unique has the unique words
```

Note that this will preserve the case of the original words.

UPDATE: As noted in the comments, it's not clear exactly what the OP needs, but I wrote the solution this way to illustrate a general technique for selecting unique representatives from a list under some "equivalence relation." In this case the equivalence relationship is word `$a` is equivalent to word `$b` if and only if `lc($a) eq lc($b)`.

Most equivalence relationships can be expressed in this way, that is, the relationship is defined by a classifier function `f()` such that `$a` is equivalent to `$b` if and only if `f($a) eq f($b)`. For instance, if we want to say that two words are equivalent if they have the same length, then `f()` would be `length()`.

So now you might see why I wrote the algorithm this way - the classifier function may not produce values that are part of the original list. In the case of `f = length`, we want to select words, but `f` of a word is a number.

Comment: Using `lc` inside the hash access is much nicer than the other solution given, as it preserves the (first matching) case from the input.

Comment: @LeoNerd What on earth are you talking about? There is no difference between using lc before and inside the hash.

Comment: I meant, as opposed to the map lc ... solution given in the other answer. This one is nicer as it returns values in their original case, not in forced-lower case.

Comment: Aha, I see now. However, that's not what the OP requested. Besides, who's to say that the original case is desireable? Usually, names are ucfirst(lc).

Comment: I'm sure that the uniq() library has more support and efficiency than this version.